# How to dispatch multiple actions from redux action creators / thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

In a small React/Redux app that I am writing, I have a thunk that looks as follow:

```
updateCategory(category){

        return function(dispatch, getState){

            dispatch({ type : types.UPDATE_CATEGORY, category });
            dispatch({ type : locationTypes.UPDATE_CATEGORY_FOR_ALL_LOCATIONS, category });

        }

    }
```

complete code:

```
    //Category Duck
    import v4 from 'node-uuid';
    import {types as locationTypes} from './locations'
    export const types = {
        UPDATE_CATEGORY:"UPDATE_CATEGORY"
    };

    const initialState = [];

    export function reducer(state = initialState, action){

        switch (action.type) {


            case types.UPDATE_CATEGORY:

                return state.map( item => item.id !== action.category.id ? item : {...action.category} );

            default:
                return state;
        }

    };

    export const actions={

        updateCategory(category){

            return function(dispatch, getState){

                dispatch({ type : types.UPDATE_CATEGORY, category });
                dispatch({ type : locationTypes.UPDATE_CATEGORY_FOR_ALL_LOCATIONS, category });

            }

        }
    }

    //Location Duck
    import v4 from 'node-uuid';

    export const types = {

        UPDATE_CATEGORY_FOR_ALL_LOCATIONS:"UPDATE_CATEGORY_FOR_ALL_LOCATIONS"
    };

    const initialState=[];

    export function reducer(state = initialState, action){

        switch (action.type) {

            case types.UPDATE_CATEGORY_FOR_ALL_LOCATIONS:

                return state.map(item => item.category.id !== action.category.id ? item : { ...item, 'category':{name:action.category.name, id:action.category.id} })

            default:
                return state;
        }

    };

    export const actions={

        updateCategoryForAllLocations(category){
            return { type : types.UPDATE_CATEGORY_FOR_ALL_LOCATIONS, category}
        }
    }


    //configStore

    import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';

    import { routerReducer, routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';//, push
    import logger from 'redux-logger';

    import * as storage from './localstorage';
    import throttle from 'lodash/throttle';

    import reducers from './duckes/rootReducer'; // Or wherever you keep your reducers

    import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

    const persistedState = storage.loadState();

    const configureStore = (history) => {

        const store = createStore(
            combineReducers({
                ...reducers,
                // router: routerReducer
            }), 
            persistedState, 
            applyMiddleware(thunk)
        );

        store.subscribe(throttle(() => {
            storage.saveState( store.getState() )
        }),1000);

        return store;

    }

    export default configureStore;
```

when calling it from a UI click handler in a connected component like this:

```
updateCategory({id:1, name:'foo')
```

I get back Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

Can you advice me on how to solve this or maybe explain why it is happening?

the component with the call looks as follows:
    /ManageCategoryPage

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import {actions as categoryActions} from '../../duckes/categories';
import CategoryForm from './CategoryForm';

import {getElementByID} from '../../utils';

class ManageCategoryPage extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        //Init state
        this.state = { 
            'category' : Object.assign({},this.props.category),
            'errors':{}
         }

        //Bind functions
        this.saveCategory=this.saveCategory.bind(this);
        this.updateCategoryState=this.updateCategoryState.bind(this);
        this.categoryExists=this.categoryExists.bind(this);
    }

    updateCategoryState(event){
      ...
    }

    categoryExists(category){
       ...
    }

    saveCategory(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        const {category}=this.state;
        this.props.actions.updateCategory(category);
        this.props.history.push('/categories');

    }

    //Render
    render(){

        return (

            <CategoryForm 
                category={this.state.category}
                locations={this.props.locations}
                onChange={this.updateCategoryState}
                onSave={this.saveCategory}
                errors={this.state.errors}/>
        )
    }

}

//Prop Types validation
ManageCategoryPage.propTypes={
    category: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    locations: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    categories: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

//Redux connect
const mapStateToProps = ({locations, categories}, ownProps) => {
    let category={id:'', name:''};
    return {
        category : getElementByID(categories, ownProps.match.params.id) || category,
        locations : locations,
        categories : categories
    };

};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {

    return { 
                'actions': bindActionCreators(categoryActions, dispatch)
           };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ManageCategoryPage);
```

Comment: Can you show the connected component?

Comment: Tnx,  Tomasz I have added the component code.

Comment: it looks fine to me. Could you recreate this project in codesandbox.io ?

Comment: Are you sure you have your thunk middleware setup properly ? Does dispatching actions from thunks works elsewhere in the project ?

Comment: The updateCategory thunk is the only thunk I have, I have actions creators that works as expected(omitted), I set up a thunk as a middlebrow in my config store, and I am not sure why my thunk is not dispatching actions, I am not sure what is missing in my setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue and actually it was a mistake of mine, I had two configStore files and I somehow imported an old version of the configStore file that i created  previously and it was missing 'thunk' as a param in applyMiddleware() call, so it means that it was applyMiddleware() instead applyMiddleware(thunk).

Comment: Tnx everyone for your help, while trying to recreate it on codesandbox.io I noticed my mistake.